# How to set attributes for writers generic objects, for instance, lines?

Tags: fme-form

How to set attributes for writers generic objects, for instance, lines?!

Writer generic objects lines are created, but without attribute because I do not know how to set attributes and values.

Comment: Do you mean objects as features ie. points, lines in .shp file? How do create the objects? Try to form your question as precise as possible. In this form it is not possible to answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [AttributeExposer](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/content/transformers/attributeexposer.htm), [AttributeCreator](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/content/transformers/attributecreator.htm), [AttributeSetter](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/content/transformers/attributesetter.htm), and [SchemaMapper](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/content/transformers/schemamapper.htm) transformers might be of use.

You might want to go into more detail including describing your current workspace (screenshots would help), input data, parameters, desired output, etc.

Comment: Yes. The Generic Writer functions the same way as any other. Provided the attributes are on the feature and the same attributes are on the output schema, then they will be written out. So a screenshot would really help.